# Unable to host symfony 2.7 application

Tags: php, symfony

I have done my php project using Symfony2 framework. Now I need to host it in a server with cPanel. The web folder in my server is public_html and my project web folder is named test. But I only can see my folders when I open project in browser...
This is my URL,
http://silverdreamtours.com/test/

It would be great help if someone can look into it

This is my file structure,

```
Root/
 ├─public_html
   ├─www
   │ ├─app.php
   │ └─...
   ├─test
     ├─app
     │ ├─config/
     │ └─ ...
     ├─ vendor/
        └─ ...
```

My app.php file in www directory,

```
<?php
    use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    //$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
    $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../test/app/autoload.php';

    // Enable APC for autoloading to improve performance.
    // You should change the ApcClassLoader first argument to a unique prefix
    // in order to prevent cache key conflicts with other applications
    // also using APC.
    /*
    $apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
    $loader->unregister();
    $apcLoader->register(true);
    */

    //require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
    //require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';
    require_once __DIR__.'/../test/app/AppKernel.php';

    $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
    //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

    // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
    //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

And app_dev.php file,

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

//$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../test/app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../test/app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

composer.json file,

```
"extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be copy your project folder to the server through ftp and include the domain pointing to your "web" folder. Some time this is not possible so you need to try in others ways.

In symfony your public folder by default is under "web" directory. So in your case you need to rename that folder to "www" [like this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory), and then copy the full project to the server in a way that your renamed www folder match with the position of the www in the server. You can not only rename that folder, also can be moved outside the symfony folder or place the app.php file in the root of project if you need that too. Just apply the configuration in the cookbook for do it in any way. However would be convenient leave the source of your project outside the public folder as I first explain.

Lets say that you a have you symfony project in a folder like this

```
your-project/
├─ app/
│  ├─ config/
│  └─ ...
├─ vendor/
│  └─ ...
└─ web/
   ├─ app.php
   └─ ...
```

Now we need to rename the "web" folder for getting this structure:

```
your-project/
├─ app/
│  ├─ config/
│  └─ ...
├─ vendor/
│  └─ ...
└─ www/
   ├─ app.php
   └─ ...
```

For doing that there are one main configurations to do. First in app/config/config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    read_from: "%kernel.root_dir%/../www"
```

If you plan just rename that folder that's all than you need to do. Now let say that this is your file structure in the server.

```
root/
├─ www/
```

If that is the case then you must copy all the files inside "your-project" folder and paste in the root, so in that way the positions of the www folders will be the same. And at end will keep like this

```
root/
    ├─ app/
    │  ├─ config/
    │  └─ ...
    ├─ vendor/
    │  └─ ...
    └─ www/
       ├─ app.php
       └─ ...
```

As you can see in this way you can host only one project in this server and beside your projects files can be mixed with others files already existing in the root folder, so, you can also pull out the www folder for getting this structure:

```
root/
   ├─www
   ├─your-project
     ├─ app/
     │  ├─ config/
     │  └─ ...
     ├─ vendor/
        └─ ...
```

For doing that the you need to change the config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
    assetic:
        read_from: "%kernel.root_dir%/../../www"
```

And also need to change the app.php and app_dev.php now inside the www folder.

```
//look for this lines and change it like this

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../your-project/app/autoload.php';
//...
require_once __DIR__.'/../your-project/app/AppKernel.php';
//..
```

With that in place now when you access to your public domain your www folder receive the request and make the call to the framework. Do again install and dump of the assets after the folders be moved.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi I tried changing "symfony-web-dir" in composer.json but it didn't work. It would be really great help if you can explain little bit more(perhaps with an example). Really sorry I'm bit new to this

Comment: Thanks so much and I tried your code but seems like it's not working for me. I updated my question with latest code.I'm really sorry to bother you like this. I'll promise not only accept your answer but tell everyone I know to upvote if you can help me on this. God bless you pal.

Comment: Not problem, but I tried that way a few times and work perfectly, so you must have other problem then. Had you tried in a local xampp first?

Comment: And I had to add my symfony project to subfolder in root since main directory is already occupied